# What does the Spanish word "you" mean in English?

Tags: definiciones

I'm taking an online class on "scientific thought" which has a transcription of the spoken video text, and the Spanish word "you" occurs in almost every lecture, even in one lecture four times (see below). Google translate simply translates it as "you" and online dictionaries and Google search for English and Spanish words so it always finds the English word "you".

What does the Spanish word "you" mean in the following excerpts, or is this some kind of transcription error?

> En medicina se desarrolló la medicina Ayurveda que fue un poco más
>   efectiva que la egipcia, de hecho, **you** operaban cataratas, una técnica
>   que se exportó a China y a otras partes del mundo.
>
> **You** que tenemos muy poca información de esta época, la historia
>   necesariamente es parcial e incompleta.
>
> En Mesoamérica, la cultura, de la cual tenemos registros más antiguos,
>   es la Olmeca. **you** tenían escritura, astronomía, calendarios, y
>   matemáticas, las cuales incluían el numero cero y manejaban una base
>   20.
>
> El desarrollo de la agricultura trajo la posibilidad de vivir en
>   grandes ciudades, lo cual permitía que no todos los miembros de una
>   población se dedicaran al mismo oficio, **you** sea estar cazando o
>   recolectando.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's supposed to be *ya*. Just a transcription error.